# When 2 regions overlap, what determines/influences the stacking order?

Tags: xsl-fo

Within one region, XSL-FO uses the z-index property to determine what to do when two objects overlap.

But what happens when two regions overlap? 
I have a body region that's 170 mm wide with some content:

```
<fo:table table border-bottom-style="solid">
    <fo:table-column column-width="171mm" column-number="1"/>
```

So the table is wider than the body region, I'm using this to draw a line (the bottom border) that extends into the region-end.

The region-end contains some artwork. I want the body region to be drawn on top of this artwork.

I've experimented with z-index properties on all elements involved, but that doesn't seem to work. The region-end keeps being drawn on top of the body region.

Is there a way to change this behavior, and draw the body region on top of the region-end? 
I'm using Antennahouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AH Formatter allows the regions to be in any order and renders them in the order in which they appear.  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-ext.html#ext-others

Comment: That's it! I changed the order in my fo:simple-page-master to list the body region last, and I got the stacking order I wanted.

Comment: PS I use Antennahouse 6.1, it works in that version too, but https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf60/docs/ahf-ext.html#ext-others doesn't list this behavior.